# Ambiguous method call intelliJ 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have two overloaded methods:

```
protected final <L extends List<D>> ResponseEntity<L> convertAndRespond(final Iterable<E> sources, final Class<L> dataListClass) { ... }

protected final <L extends List<D>> ResponseEntity<L> convertAndRespond(final Page<E> sources, final Class<L> dataListClass) { ... }
```

where `interface Page<T> implements Iterable<T>`

I have method which finally creates page object and returns the following method call:

```
convertAndRespond(page, A.class);
```

IntelliJ gives me here compile error: **Ambiguous method call**
Although my application builds & runs pretty well. What could be the issue?

**The interesting thing here is that previously IntelliJ 14 were not showing there any compilation problems.**

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is telling you that the compiler could pick either method to run.  After all, the class Page *is a* Iterable.

This may be dependent on the compiler you've chosen for IntelliJ but either way, it is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I am using there Project SDK (Java 1.8.0.25), Language level 8

Comment: As long as it compiles properly, this is correct code. I also have this problem with Intellij 15.