# Java Behavior in case of similar method signatures in Parent and Child

Tags: java

I have 3 following cases for a method in Parent class and Child class with same names and different parameters.

Case 1 :

```
class Parent
{
    public void hello(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }       
}

class Child extends Parent
{   
    public void hello(String obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

Case 2 :

```
class Parent
{
    public void hello(String obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }   
}

class Child extends Parent
{

    public void hello(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

Case 3 :

```
class Parent
{
    public void hello(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }   
    public void hello(String obj)
    {
        System.out.println("String in Same Class");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
}
```

Have main() as follows :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.hello(null);
    }
```

Output For Case 1 :

```
Child
```

Output for Case 2:

```
Parent
```

Output for case 3:

```
String in Same Class
```

I have Observed that in all the three cases, every time method which has String parameter gets called. Doesn't matter if it is in Child or Parent. I am really confused, because 'null' should create some ambiguity or method from child class should have been selected as its an object of Child. Why this behavior?

Comment: There are JVM rules at play here, which basically say that in cases where it is ambiguous as to which method to call, the method with the more specific signature will get called.  Since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, and therefore more specific than `Object`, the string version is being called.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of something, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to work around Ambiguous method call without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799302/is-there-a-way-to-work-around-ambiguous-method-call-without-casting)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Java Language Specification [§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) Choosing the Most Specific Method

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run- time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

In your case, there is a method that accepts an `Object` and one that accepts `String`. Since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, the latter is more specific and hence will be chosen. For more details regarding what is considered more specific, see the language specification.

Comment: quoting the JLS gives an absolute +1 from me. I would just add that since these are overloads the method to call is a compile time thing...